# SQL To Get Me Repeat Visits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of vehicle visits. The vehicle tag number (`PlateID`) is stored in it along with a timestamp (`TimeStamp`).

I need to query the table by date range and get only the records where a vehicle has visited multiple times. I want to show the plate number, the number of visits, and the last time it visited.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: sorry, too hastily done. I'm using SQL Server Express.

I've tried something like this:

```
Select PlateID1, count(1) as VisitCount 
From ActivityLog
Where (TimeStamp > '10/19/1977' And TimeStamp < '12/12/2017')
Group By PlateID1
Order By VisitCount Desc
```

But this returns all records, where I just want the ones that have visited more than once. Also, I can't get additional columns with this query, like `TimeStamp`, `Location`, etc etc.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Try this

```
Select PlateID1, count(1) as VisitCount from ActivityLog
where (TimeStamp > '10/19/1977' and TimeStamp < '12/12/2017')
Group by PlateID1
having count(PlateID1) > 1
Order BY VisitCount Desc
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms180199(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It tells me "incorrect syntax near the keyword having".  When I move having VisitCount > 1 above the Order by clause it tells me "invalid column name 'VisitCount'"

Comment: Try to replace `having VisitCount > 1` by `having count(PlateID1) > 1`, looks like aliases are not authorized there.